# Unbalanced spacing with braces in mtpro2

Tags: spacing, mtpro

The code `$\LEFTRIGHT\{\}{S_n}$` produces

[image: Unbalanced]

whereras the code `$\left\{ S_n \right\}$` produces

[image: Balanced].

Is this a bug or feature? As the content in the braces grow larger, the visual effect of the unbalance is reduced. The above output of `\LEFTRIGHT` really looks ugly to my eyes.

Note: my preamble has `\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}`

Comment: Note also that `\PARENS{S_N}` and `\LEFTRIGHT(){S_n}` behave differently.

Comment: `$\left\{S_n\right\}$` is wrong to begin with; so is `\LEFTRIGHT`, independently from the strange behavior. Use automatic sizing only when really necessary, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is in the definition of `\LEFTRIGHT`, which means it is so “by design”:

```
\def\LEFTRIGHT#1#2#3{%
 \specdelim@#1%
 \ifspecdelim@
  \LEFTRIGHT@#1.{\vc@nt@r{#3}}%
 \else
  \left#1
  \vc@nt@r{#3}%
  \right.%
 \fi
 \kern-2\nulldelimiterspace\mskip-\thinmuskip
 \specdelim@#2%
 \ifspecdelim@
  \LEFTRIGHT@.#2{\vphantom{\vc@nt@r{#3}}}%
 \else
  \left.%
  \vphantom{\vc@nt@r{#3}}%
  \right#2%
 \fi}
```

For strange reasons, `\mskip-\thinmuskip` is added (it's the same as `\!`).

Indeed, if you try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}

$\{S\}$

$\left\{S\right\}$

$\LEFTRIGHT\{\}{S\,}$

\end{document}
```

you get

[image]